# Arrays are far more efficient that ArrayLists?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have recently written a code, here is the relevant part of it:

```
int n=100000;
int[] euler=new int[n+1],arr=new int[n+1],brr=new int[n+1]; 
ArrayList[] list = new ArrayList[n+1]; //reverse euler. list[4]=5,8,10,12.
use.makeEuler(euler); 
for(int i=7; i<=n; i++)
    brr[euler[i]]++;
for(int i=7; i<=n; i++)
{
    if (list[euler[i]] == null) 
        list[euler[i]] = new ArrayList<Integer>(brr[euler[i]].length);
    list[euler[i]].add(i);
}
for(int i=n; i>=6; i--)
{
    for(int j=euler[i]+2; j<i; j+=2)
    {
        if(list[j]==null) continue;
        for(int k=list[j].size()-1; k>=0 && (int)list[j].get(k)>i ; k--)
        {
            arr[i]+=1+arr[(int) list[j].get(k)]; arr[i]%=100000000;
        }
    }
}
```

And noticed something very odd. Apparently if I replace the functions on the ArrayList by functions on an equal array, the code runs much faster (From 83 sec to 27 sec). That is:

```
Object[] x;
for(int i=n; i>=6; i--)
{
    for(int j=euler[i]+2; j<i; j+=2)
    {
        if(list[j]==null) continue;
        x=list[j].toArray();
        for(int k=x.length-1; k>=0 && (int)x[k]>i ; k--)
        {
            arr[i]+=1+arr[(int) x[k]]; arr[i]%=100000000;
        }
    }
}
```

A. Why does that happen?
B. Is it possible to make Arraylists work equally fast? (because copying ArrayList to arrays for itself takes much time).

Thanks!

Edit: There's one thing I don't understand. Why does it resize after I'm done adding/removing numbers from the Arraylists?

Edit2: I improved the code so now it doesn't resize at all. This reduced running time from 83 to 59 sec, but it's still significantly larger than 27 sec (when I am using arrays). Why is that and how do I farther improve it?

Comment: ArrayList has some overhead

Comment: ArrayList have to re size them-self

Comment: Did you try ` list[euler[i]] = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);` that will create an ArrayList of size `n` so it will not have to resize. This will be an equivalent of your non-ArrayList code. Otherwise your comparison is not valid as conditions are different.

Comment: This would throw an overflow. Do you know any other stracture I can use instead of ArrayLists such that it wouldn't make and overflow but also work efficiently?

Comment: @user2705335 Why would it create an overflow? Passing an initial size to the ArrayList will not limit its growing abilities; it will just give it an initial size. If you want more control over the size, you may want to use the ensureCapacity-function as well. Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ensureCapacity(int) to find out more.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough, I meant OutOfMemoryError. Btw, I don't understand this resize. I mean, why would the ArrayList resize if I don't add or remove any members at the loop (which is 99% of the running time).

Comment: @user2705335 While it's not adding or removing items it won't resize, no. But when you add elements it will increase its size and not just to fit that one new element; indeed the new capacity will be calculated by the formula `newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3) / 2 + 1` (at least in Java 1.6). That means that if you have many lists they're probably all bigger than they have to be. Once you've added all elements you want you could reduce their sizes with the `trimToSize()` function as explained under http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#trimToSize()

Comment: Oh I see. I attempted to trimToSize() every Arraylist in that array, but this did not improve runTime, why is that? And what would?

Comment: Trimming them will make sure they don't use more space than they require, which is a good thing. However it won't solve all possible problems. Each time you call the `get(int)` function on an ArrayList it will check whether the List is big enough to include an element at that position. Now, in Java 6 this will call the `RangeCheck(int)` function which will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` with an error message it builds in the function...

Comment: ...In Java 7 the function has been renamed `rangeCheck(int)` and it calls a separate function to create a potential error message; I'm not sure about when the String would be built but it might make a difference. Which version of Java are you using? If it's Java 6, an update to 7 may substantially increase the speed of your calculations.

Comment: I am pretty positive it's 7, how do I verify it?

Comment: There are many ways... For example, open a command line prompt (on Windows this would be cmd.exe, on different systems I trust you know what to do) and type `java -version`.

Comment: It says 1.7.0_25, so that can't be the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: In that case I'd guess it's all the overhead from the get function. When you call `get(int)` it will check whether the value is in range and if so it will get the object from the internal array (which is of the type `Object[]` and cast it to the generic type you are using. All of this takes time of course. In your second solution you get that `Object[]` (well, a copy of it which is only as big as it has to be) and you cast the values yourself. You do not however check whether the array is big enough. My guess is that this saves you those seconds.

Answer (score 5):

> A. Why does that happen?

Because `ArrayList` is using an array underneath. By default the size of the array is 10. When you try to add the 11th element a new bigger array has to be created and all the values from the smaller array has to be copied to the new array. In your case, since you are adding 100000 elements this happens numerous times and it is the cause of the difference in performance.

> B. Is it possible to make Arraylists work equally fast? (because copying ArrayList to arrays for itself takes much time).

Yes, when creating `ArrayList` instances, use the constructor that allows to provide the initial capacity of the [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29), i.d.:

```
public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)
```

> Constructs an empty list with the specified initial capacity.
>
> Parameters:
>   initialCapacity - the initial capacity of the list

Comment: I'm not sure I quite put my mind over this initialCapacity. If I got you correctly, then this wouldn't help me much. I am using an array of ArrayLists, where every ArrayLists's length can move from 0 to 10^4, and so making all intialCapacity 10^4 would throw an overflow

Comment: BTW, I think your code is incomplete or incorrect because you never instantiate `ArrayLists` so `list[0]`..`list[n]` are always `null`.

Comment: This is just part of my code, it's not so long so I think it'd be best if I just put it all in. Look at my edit.

Comment: `list[euler[i]] = new ArrayList<Integer>(x);` where `x` can either be set to an arbitrary-higher-than-10 value like 10000 or if it is possible be computed from the `n` value.

Comment: x=10000 apparently just increased run-time to 108 sec. :/ BTW, I just found I was wrong with my estimate, and there are many ArrayLists with up to 10^5 values.

Comment: Tell me, is it possible to convert ArrayList[] to a  sequence of arrays with different lengths?

Comment: ok, my suggestion in that case is: check how many entries are stored in every list `int i=0; for(ArrayList a : list) System.out.println(i+ "="+a.size());` and come up with a formula that will compute the initial size for every list to avoid ArrayList resizing.

Comment: I solved this not with a formula, but by using another array that counts   number of numbers m with Euler phi(m) = n. This has improved running time from 83 to 59, but is still not as low as it is when I replace ArrayLists with arrays. Why is that?